# Concatenate strings in key of plain object

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, object, for-loop

So I have this plain object

```
var data = {};
```

And i want to fill it with key-value pairs in a for loop like this

```
for(var i=0; i<n; i++){
    $.extend(
        data,
        {
            'a'+toString(i): someFunction(i),
            'b'+toString(i): someFunction(i)
        };
    );
};
```

but seems like it's impossible to concatenate strings when defining the key.
Is there any neat way to do what I need, because I feel like my approach is lame from the very begining.

Thanks.

Comment: `'a'+toString(i)` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) since the keys are dynamic

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    data['a' + toString(i)] = someFunction(i);
    data['b' + toString(i)] = someFunction(i);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this syntax

```
for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    data['a'+toString(i)] = someFunction(i);
}
```

To use a non-literal key with an object you need to use the square bracket notation. This allows you to create dynamic keys.

Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more info on square bracket notation